# What is limit of passing envelope ids in listStatusChanges api of docusign?

Tags: docusignapi

I am passing comma separated list of envelope ids into [listStatusChanges](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/listStatusChanges/) api of docusign. For 53 records I am getting response but for 54th envelope id I am not getting response.

Is there any limit on passing number of envelope ids?

Comment: What do you mean by you're getting a response for 53 but not for 54?  Please show more details like the requests you're making and the response you are getting.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41713964/liststatuschanges-api-gives-error-after-passing-more-than-50-envelopeids

Answer (score 0):

Web servers and browsers usually limit the length of HTTP get requests. See a more detailed explaination [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request).

Since the envelopeId is a GUID, adding more than 50 guids results in a long query string that will hit the webserver limit.

I suggest you use other query parameters like from_date specified in the [documentation](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/listStatusChanges/)