# listStatusChanges api gives error after passing more than 50 envelopeids

Tags: docusignapi

I am calling Envelopes: listStatusChanges api to fetch envelope statuses. I am passing envelope ids(comma seperated list) as a parameter to this method, upto 50 envelope ids it gives me result but as soon as I pass more than 50 envelope ids it gives me following error. I aslo tried with Docusign Apiexplorer by passing same envelope ids list but the result is same. Is there any limitation on passing these envelope ids?

'error: "    404 - File or directory not found.

## Server Error

### 404 - File or directory not found.

#### The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

"'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 404 error is being thrown by the webserver as the length of the URL of your HTTP GET request is too long. See more detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request)

You can instead use other parameters(for ex: from_date) on the [listStatusChanges](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/listStatusChanges/) api to query the list of envelopes. You can then filter the response based on envelopeId's you are looking for.

Another more efficient option would be to use [Docusign Connect](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/usage/status_and_events.html) to get notifications on Envelope Status changes.

Comment: I was passing envelope ids so that I can get statuses for those envelopes only, if I pass from_date then it will return lot more data. I am also using Connect but implemented polling in case listener goes down. Can I break my envelope ids list in chunks and call 'listStatusChanges' for that specific set? Whether it will break api call limit? I think limit is for if I call this api multiple times for same envelope, is that right?

Comment: Breaking the envelopeids into chunks and calling the listStatusChanges api multiple times will still increase your API invocation count.  I think your best option will be to retrieve the envelopes using from_date and filter the result set based on the envelope id's you are looking for.

Comment: OK this will do the trick, thanks. But do I need to pass 'from_date' is specific format or it can accept any format?

Comment: it is not limited to just these,  but "from_date" should accept (mm/dd/yyyy , mm-dd-yyyy, yyyy/mm/dd, yyyy-mm-dd)